# Computing a new variable conditional on levels of another variable

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a new variable (e.g., col3) whereby the values for the final variable are computed differently conditional on levels of a different variable (e.g., col2).

I have tried a few different methods such as simply creating new variables as well as mutate with dplyr. My current data looks like

```
> df
Grade Theta
1      -2.39
2       0.11
3       0.30
4       0.23
```

and the conversation mechanisms to the new variables would be that

```
df$sstest1[df$Grade=='1']=(((df$Theta--.0961)/.657)*15)+100

df$sstest2[df$Grade=='2']=(((df$Theta--.0406)/.631)*15)+100

df$sstest3[df$Grade=='3']=(((df$Theta-.163)/.621)*15)+100

df$sstest4[df$Grade=="4"]=(((df$Theta-.318)/.702)*15)+100
```

In this way, the expectation is that the new df should be

```
> df
Grade Theta   sstest1  sstest2  sstest3 sstest4
1      -2.39  47.627
2       0.11           103.58
3       0.30                     103.31
4       0.23                             98.12
```

However the result I obtain is

```
> df
Grade Theta   sstest1  sstest2  sstest3 sstest4
1      -2.39  47.627
2       0.11           44.15
3       0.30                     38.33
4       0.23                             42.14
```

where the sstest1 value is correct but I receive warnings of

```
Warning df$sstest1[df$Grade=='1']=(((df$Theta--.0961)/.657)*15)+100 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Warning df$sstest2[df$Grade=='2']=(((df$Theta--.0406)/.631)*15)+100 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Warning df$sstest3[df$Grade=='3']=(((df$Theta-.163)/.621)*15)+100 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Warning df$sstest4[df$Grade=="4"]=(((df$Theta-.318)/.702)*15)+100 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Before getting into full ifelse or mutate statements, I'm trying to reconcile how sstest2-sstest4 are producing incorrect values where sstest1 is producing a correct value.

Answer (score 2):

Well, on the right hand side you compute the value for each Theta for all rows. And the first value is taken into account for each row no matter the grade. Execute `(((df$Theta--.0406)/.631)*15)+100` and you will get a value for each row. This vector of 4 elements is assigned to only one row in `sstest2`. Therefore the first vector element is used instead of the second one.

Here is a dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Grade = 1:4,
                 Theta = c(-2.39, 0.11, 0.3, 0.23))

thetafun <- function(theta, grade) {
  a <- c(-0.961, -0.0406, 0.161, 0.318)
  b <- c(0.657, 0.631, 0.621, 0.702)
  return(((theta - a[grade]) / b[grade]) * 15 + 100)
}

df %>% 
  mutate(sstest = thetafun(Theta, Grade)) %>%
  spread(key = Grade, value = sstest, sep = "")
```

As you can see the final `df` could be called `sstest`:

```
  Theta Grade1 Grade2 Grade3 Grade4
1 -2.39  67.37     NA     NA     NA
2  0.11     NA  103.6     NA     NA
3  0.23     NA     NA     NA  98.12
4  0.30     NA     NA  103.4     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

A base r approach is to limit the right hand side of the equation to the same records as the left hand side:

```
df$sstest1[df$Grade=='1']=(((df$Theta[df$Grade=='1']--.0961)/.657)*15)+100

df$sstest2[df$Grade=='2']=(((df$Theta[df$Grade=='2']--.0406)/.631)*15)+100

df$sstest3[df$Grade=='3']=(((df$Theta[df$Grade=='3']-.163)/.621)*15)+100

df$sstest4[df$Grade=="4"]=(((df$Theta[df$Grade=='4']-.318)/.702)*15)+100
```